# set chart name in Xlwings

Tags: python, excel, windows, charts, xlwings

When I plot a chart by xlwings, I can't change chart name. The chart name and legend name are still 'Series 1', but the upper left corner shows 'Feb sales' which is I want

```
import xlwings as xw

sht = xw.Book().sheets[0]
sht.range('A1').value = list(zip([1, 2, 3, 4]))
chart = sht.charts.add()
chart.set_source_data(sht.range('A1').expand())
chart.chart_type = 'line_markers'
chart.name='Feb sales'
#chart.api.ChartTitle.Text = 'Feb sales'
#chart.delete()
```

[created chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmW8u.png)

Is this a known issue? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
import xlwings as xw

sht = xw.Book().sheets[0]
sht.range('A1').value = list(zip([1, 2, 3, 4]))
chart = sht.charts.add()
chart.set_source_data(sht.range('A1').expand())
chart.chart_type = 'line_markers'

chart.api[1].SetElement(2)  # Place chart title at the top
chart.api[1].ChartTitle.Text = 'Feb sales'  # Change text of the chart title
```

The expression `chart.api` returns a tuple with two COM wrappers. I'm not really sure why there are two COM wrappers, but it seems that you need the second one to access the chart. Hence the use of `chart.api[1]` here.

With the attribute [`xlwings.Chart.name`](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Chart.name) you can set an excel chart's [`Name`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vba/excel-vba/articles/chart-name-property-excel) property (as you did in your question's code), but this is not a property that is used for display. To achieve display of text in the chart you need to set the excel chart's [`ChartTitle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vba/excel-vba/articles/chart-charttitle-property-excel) property (as done in this answer's code).

Comment: yes, this works! I was wondering could I change chart name just by xlwings since I noticed there is a chart.name function in the documentation?