# Chart objects in xlwings

Tags: python, pywin32, xlwings

The code snippet came from the official documentation of `xlwings` [here](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.main.Charts.add) and it is the setup for my question.

```
import xlwings as xw
sht = xw.Book().sheets[0]
sht.range('A1').value = [['Foo1', 'Foo2'], [1, 2]]
chart = sht.charts.add()
chart.set_source_data(sht.range('A1').expand())
chart.chart_type = 'line'
chart.name
```

Running `print(chart.api)` outputs the tuple below.

```
(<xlwings._xlwindows.COMRetryObjectWrapper at 0x1fcd60c9a90>, <xlwings._xlwindows.COMRetryObjectWrapper at 0x1fcd60c9f28>)
```

If I want to use the [api](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Chart.api) attribute to do some basic chart manipulation like remove the legend and add a title, it only works if I do it to `chart.api[1]`. For instance the code below works fine. It removes the chart legend and adds a title.

```
chart.api[1].HasLegend = 0
chart.api[1].SetElement(2)
chart.api[1].ChartTitle.Text = 'A title'
```

However, anything I do to `chart.api[0]` yields an error, (for instance `print(chart.api[0].HasLegend)` yields an error). I can't understand what kind of object this is or how it is useful. I can't find anything regarding this in the official documentation.

Finally my question is: what is the object at the index 0 above? Please, help me grok what it is.

Answer (score 0):

There is another post that addresses your question about the object at the index 0.

[set chart name in Xlwings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44910566/set-chart-name-in-xlwings?rq=1)

> The expression chart.api returns a tuple with two COM wrappers. I'm
>   not really sure why there are two COM wrappers, but it seems that you
>   need the second one to access the chart. Hence the use of chart.api[1]
>   here.